# Python takes 3ms while Spring takes 80ms to execute the select query from Azure SQL Server?

Tags: python, spring, azure-sql-database, hikaricp, azure-sql-server

I have a simple Table created in Azure SQL Database

Below Python script takes only **3ms** to to execute the select query from Azure SQL Server

```
import os
import sys
import logging, logging.handlers
import getopt
import pyodbc

# set up logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)s %(message)s'))
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(console)

logger = logging.getLogger("purgeStaleTags")

server = 'sqlsrv-01.database.windows.net'
database = 'db'
username = 'user'
password = 'p@$$word'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

logger.info("Before Connect")
connection=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;')
logger.info("Before Cursor")
cursor=connection.cursor()
logger.info("After Cursor")
cursor.execute("SELECT item_id FROM offer_table WHERE offer_id = 23583");
records=cursor.fetchall()
logger.info(len(records))
logger.info("After Query")
```

**Logs**

```
>>> logger.info("Before Connect")
2022-01-05 19:00:30,638 purgeStaleTags INFO Before Connect
>>> connection=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;')
>>> logger.info("Before Cursor")
2022-01-05 19:00:30,871 purgeStaleTags INFO Before Cursor
>>> cursor=connection.cursor()
>>> logger.info("After Cursor")
2022-01-05 19:00:30,871 purgeStaleTags INFO After Cursor
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT item_id FROM offer_table WHERE offer_id = 23583");
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x7f05f45280b0>
>>> records=cursor.fetchall()
>>> logger.info(len(records))
2022-01-05 19:00:30,884 purgeStaleTags INFO 30
>>> logger.info("After Query")
2022-01-05 19:00:30,884 purgeStaleTags INFO After Query
```

But the below spring application takes **80ms** to execute the select query from Azure SQL Server?

**Java Application:**

```
public class JDBCSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...

        try {
            Connection conn = dataSource().getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs ;
            try {
                LocalDateTime executionStartTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                System.out.println("Select Query Execution Started: " + dtf.format(executionStartTime));
                
                rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT item_id FROM offer_table WHERE offer_id = 23583");

                executionEndTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                System.out.println("Select Query Execution Completed:  " + dtf.format(executionEndTime));
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
                return; // Exit if there was an error
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public static DataSource dataSource(){
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://....;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("...");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("...");
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
INFO  : 01.06.2022:0032 (31.802) [[]main] HikariDataSource: springHikariCP - Starting... 
INFO  : 01.06.2022:0032 (33.314) [[]main] HikariDataSource: springHikariCP - Start completed. 
Execution Started: 2022/01/06 00:32:33.436
INFO  : 01.06.2022:0032 (33.437) [[]main] HikariDataSource: springHikariCP - Starting... 
INFO  : 01.06.2022:0032 (33.927) [[]main] HikariDataSource: springHikariCP - Start completed. 
Select Query Execution Started: 2022/01/06 00:32:34.043
Select Query Execution Completed:  2022/01/06 00:32:34.122
```

Where is the delay? How do I fix this so that the Spring application will not take more than 2ms.

Comment: Just checking.  Have you tried timing more than one query?  It's possible that Azure does more setup and initialization that Python does, but that subsequent queries will be quicker.

Comment: Yes, I tried with 5 select queries. Python takes 12ms to 22ms and spring takes 350ms

Comment: Try to connect via `DriverManager` JDBC API instead of via HikakiCP `DataSource`. Maybe it's HikariCP's lazy loading or something (no idea). Microbenchmarking Java programs is hard: it's generally recommended to run the code on repeat for a couple of minutes before measuring so that JVM will have a chance to compile Java bytecode into native code.

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko - Thank you, DriverManager took ~400ms

Comment: As a sanity check - have you tried benchmarking against a local SQL server - do you see any noticeable difference in runtimes?

Comment: Yes, the java app on the laptop takes 6ms with local  Sql server

Comment: Azure SQL Server and AKS are on the same VNET. Azure SQL server uses the private endpoint

Comment: Use these timing methods for python and check time in your code and check if your not mistaken in timing option: `start_time=time.time()` `end_time=time.time()` `print('time: ' +str(end_time-start_time))`

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: you are probably comparing apples with pears**: you are missing a `cursor.fetch` to on the Python side.

Both the Java and the Python program are written in a style that suggests you have a basic level of knowledge of both languages and you are probably working hard to improve your skill. This is admirable, but your skillset is not enough to do performance comparison.

Assuming that people who developed the JVM implementation or the driver library you are using did a worse job than the guys who developed the Python VM or the Python library you are using is not realistic. **You should trust both engineers because the skill level of people involved in writing the implementation of the JVM and the Python VM is normally very high, and that's the same for popular library.** There is a community behind, and bugs gets spotted quickly.

**Let's try, for fun, to do some investigation**

**A reproducible experiment**

If I wanted to investigate the topic, I would provide a **clear, reproducible scenario** via an *open-source GitHub repository* including:

- Python *distribution* used to test the code. Are you using CPython? 3.10.0? Are you using PyPython? Which version of the libraries are you using? I would use poetry + Docker to ensure the build can be reproducible
- JVM ? OpenJDK? Azuli? What version? What version of the JDBC library for Azure SQL Server are you using? I would use Gradle, or Maven, or whatever build tool you like, and Docker

Then, I would ensure I am using tools that allow me to obtain reliable performance metrics. For example, Python is interpreted but if the library is shipped as wheel for your architecture, it might be relying on a compiled C implementation which can be much faster than the JVM implementation on a single execution. However, repeated code executions by the JVM activate the JIT compiler that compiles Java bytecode into machine code improving performances. As you see, understanding performance requires understanding how the two languages are executed, and this is not a beginner-type level of skill.

**Different semantics**

As someone with more than a decade of Java experience, I can tell no-one today interacts with relational databases using directly the JDBC API. People started to use ORM more than a decade ago, and today they probably use tool like JOOQ.

After giving a quick read on the pyodbc documentation I think that a `pyodbc.cursor` and a `ResultSet` are two different data structure. The cursor does not retrieve the data immediately, you need to call a `fetch` method. You are comparing the time it takes to pull all the records (in Java) from the database to the time it takes to pull only the count of records in the result (in Python). The first operation requires transferring more data, and therefore it takes longer.

================ Old ================

There are many reasons why you might be experiencing those performance issues, including different drivers and configuration.

The one obvious difference reading your code is that in one case you are retrieving the connection, while in the other case you are creating the connection. HikariCP is a known connection pool implementation in Java, and it is optimized for production workloads. Your python code instead will create a connection at each execution, and if executed in a for loop will result in a DoS attack to the server.

I would try to remove the connection pool from the Java process and benchmark the code again.

Comment: Without HikariCP it is taking 400ms to execute.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: He uses `fetchall`. And if JDBC is slow, no amount of ORMs will make it faster.